# Custom container using as base image Databricks Runtime ML

Tags: databricks

I would like to create a docker image based on the databricks runtime for machine learning and extend it further.
The base runtime i can simply extend in a dockerfile by doing:

```
FROM databricksruntime/standard:9.x
```

Can i do something similar for the ML runtime?
As a follow-up can I see the source code of the ml runtime?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ML Runtime = Standard Runtime + ML Libs.

`Databricks Runtime 10.2 ML is built on top of Databricks Runtime 10.2.`
[Reference](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/10.2ml.html#new-features-and-improvements)

You can recreate it by installing the libraries mentioned [here](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/10.2ml.html#libraries).

ver 10.2 is used as an example in this answer.